# Referencing external model in API Gateway without using API ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema, serverless-framework

I'm writing an API Gateway model using JSON Schema, and deploying it using Serverless framework. According to [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-models) it's possible to reference a model that's defined in a different file (but in the same API) using

```
"$ref": "https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/{restapi_id}/models/{model_name}"
```

The problem is that this requires knowing the API ID. In my case, the model will be reused across several APIs, each with it's own ID, so it doesn't make sense to hardcode the ID in the model.

Is there any way to either reference an external model without using the API ID, or inject the API ID into the model during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the model and save it in a config file to be used later. This isn't necessarily what you want, but it gives you version control over the standard models and lets you use them across services.

Example, using [serverless-aws-documentation](https://github.com/9cookies/serverless-aws-documentation):

in serverless.yml

```
custom:
  documentation:
    models: ${file(./conf/api/methodResponse/models.yml):models}

plugins:
  - serverless-aws-documentation
```

in the referenced models.yml:

```
models:
  -
    name: EmptyModel
    contentType: "application/json"
    schema:
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
      title: "Empty/Passthrough Response"
      type: object
```

Note that the "$schema" field seems to be optional, I believe, at least my tests deployed and ran without it. I just kept it in because AWS' template uses it.

That will give you local control over the model. This will mean a bit of extra work on your end to synchronize models across stacks.

Now, if you want to use an existing model in another service by reference and *not* by re-deploying it, I'm not entirely sure if that's possible. CloudFormation Model objects seem to only be identified by their model name able to be associated with a single ApiGatewayRestApi object at a time. When I try to deploy the same model name across stacks it happily obliges and the old model remains unchanged. There may be a way I'm missing, though?

Answer (score 0):

*Update: The solution that I originally posted worked in some cases but not in others. I have now posted a solution that will generally work (and is much simpler).*

I just ran into the same problem, how to keep the API ID in those model references not hardcoded. This question is already somewhat old but since it has taken me several hours to find the answer, I'll post it here for posterity.

Say you have a request model called *CreateUserRequest* and you want to factor out the *User* schema, then put the following into your serverless.yaml:

```
...
custom:
  documentation: 
    models:
      -
        name: "User"
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema: ${file(models/user.json)}
      -
        name: "CreateUserRequest"
        description: "User to be created"
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema:
          $ref: "{{model: User}}"
```

The JSON schema goes into the *user.json* file in the *models* subfolder. If you want to reference other JSON schemas from within the *user.json* file, there is a special way to do that in serverless-aws-documentation:

```
    {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "description": "A system user",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "ID of the object"
        },
        "identity": {
            "$ref": "{{model: UserIdentity}}"
        },
        "profile": {
            "$ref": "{{model: UserProfile}}"
        }
    }
}
```

And in your serverless.yaml file you'll need to make those referenced schema files known as models, too.

```
custom:
  documentation: 
    models:
      ...
      -
        name: "UserIdentity"
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema: ${file(api-models/user-identity.json)}

      -
        name: "UserProfile"
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema: ${file(api-models/user-profile.json)}
```

Note that the references within these JSON schema files are not valid JSON schema references, so you for example can't load them with a JSON schema validator (at least not directly). It is just what serverless-aws-documentation expects. Would be much nicer if it was able to support true JSON schema references, but then I also don't have the time to contribute such an enhancement.